# AutoHotkey: Multiple loops, same timer, asynchronous

Tags: loops, asynchronous, timer, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a Keybind for a game. Basically all it does is hold 1 and 2 down for 1000ms and then stop for 1200ms, then repeat. Numpad0 toggles it.

However, i want it to be asynchronous. So i tried adding a sleep between the timers. But it only works one time and then starts to execute both loops at the same time.

I hope someone can help! :)

```
Numpad0::
autofire := !autofire

if autofire
{
SetTimer, gun1, 1200
sleep 600
SetTimer, gun2, 1200
}
else
{
settimer, gun1, off
settimer, gun2, off
}
Return

gun1:
sendinput {1 down}
sleep 1000
sendinput {1 up}
return

gun2:
sendinput {2 down}
sleep 1000
sendinput {2 up}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

The sleep statements in each timer blocks the other timer from launching on schedule.

Documentation for Autohotkey [Threads](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Threads.htm):

> Although AutoHotkey doesn't actually use multiple threads, it
>   simulates some of that behavior: If a second thread is started -- such
>   as by pressing another hotkey while the previous is still running --
>   **the current thread will be interrupted (temporarily halted)** to allow
>   the new thread to become current. If a third thread is started while
>   the second is still running, both the second and first will be in a
>   dormant state, and so on.

**This is your code with additional timers replacing the sleeps:**

```
Numpad0::
  autofire := !autofire

  if (autofire)
    SetTimer gun1down, -1200
  else
  {
    SetTimer gun1down, off
    SetTimer gun1up, off
    SetTimer gun2down, off
    SetTimer gun2up, off
  }
  return

gun1down:
  sendinput {1 down}
  SetTimer gun2up, -400
  return
gun1up:
  sendinput {1 up}
  SetTimer gun1down, -200
  return
gun2down:
  sendinput {2 down}
  SetTimer gun1up, -400
  return
gun2up:
  sendinput {2 up}
  SetTimer gun2down, -200
  return
```

Comment: Hey,

thank you for your help. So i tried the code but it doesnt work at all. All it does is trigger gun1 one time and then stops.

Comment: I fixed a bug. Please try again. Also, try running the code in isolation (right click the autohotkey icon and chose "edit this script."  Save your existing script. Replace it in its entirety with the above code. Save it. Right click the autohotkey icon again and chose "reload this script")